# Emotion Recognition Dataset creation

Tags: python, opencv

I want to create an emotion recognition dataset just like fer2013. But, I couldn't find any tutorial on it.

So far, I tried this.
First, i opened the fer2013 dataset with notepad++, and took a look.
It had something like this.
emotion,pixels,Usage
0,70 80 82 72 58 58 48 ... 106 109 82,Training

Now, i used opencv and did this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 
'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

img = cv2.imread('self-download.jpg')
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(grayscale, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    roi_gray = grayscale[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('output', roi_gray)
arr = np.array(roi_gray)

np.savetxt('grayscale', arr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I gives me a large array of pixels and just by comparing I can tell that it's not the correct process.

Comment: you save only last face, you should create list for all faces and add other informations. And resize all faces to the same size. `fer2013` has all images 48x48.

Comment: you should reshape array to create flatten array `arr = arr.flatten()` or `arr = arr.reshape(arr.size)` and then you get all pixels in one row in file.

Comment: using `frm="%i"` in `savetxt('grayscale', arr, frm="%i")` you can save pixels as integer values like in `fer2013`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep all information I would use normal list which later I will save using module `csv`

```
data = []
```

Image would need to be flattened and eventually resized to have less pixels

```
roi_gray = grayscale[y:y+h, x:x+w]
roi_gray = cv2.resize(roi_gray, (24, 24))
roi_gray = roi_gray.flatten()
```

I also convert pixels to string with numbers separated by space

```
pixels_str = ' '.join(str(x) for x in roi_gray)
```

and now I can create row with data

```
row = [0, pixels_str, 'Training']
```

and append row to all data

```
data.append(row)
```

After that i can easily save it

```
with open('grayscale.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvwriter.writerow(['emotion', 'pixels', 'Usage'])
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
```

---

```
import cv2
import csv

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

img = cv2.imread('self-download.jpg')
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

data = []

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale, 1.3, 5)
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    roi_gray = grayscale[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    roi_gray = cv2.resize(roi_gray, (24, 24))
    roi_gray = roi_gray.flatten()
    pixels_str = ' '.join(str(x) for x in roi_gray)
    row = [0, pixels_str, 'Training']
    data.append(row)

with open('grayscale', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvwriter.writerow(['emotion', 'pixels', 'Usage'])
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
```

Comment: it would need different values in columns `emotion` (0...6) and `Usage` ("Training", "PublicTest")